# Where is "woocommerce_before_customer_login_form"?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hello Can anyone please tell me that where is "woocommerce_before_customer_login_form" in WooCommerce. I need to edit this...

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually located at : `/templates/myaccount/form-login.php`  in woocommerce plugin. You need to override it to your theme in woocommerce folder or you can hook it at the follow in `functions.php`.

```
function action_woocommerce_before_customer_login_form(  ) { 
    // make action magic happen here... 
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', 'action_woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: I just need to ask you something more. Now I am trying to edit "woocommerce_account_navigation". Currently, my navigation is showing the username and I want to show the first name instead of the username, can you please tell me how can I achieve that. Thank you in advance

Comment: You can do that by editing the file myaccount/navigation.php. First copy that file to the theme.